# How to produce ReferenceAssemblies with dotnet

Tags: .net-core

I'm struggling with the following problem: I added `<ProduceReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceReferenceAssembly>` to my CSPROJ (and I also tried it with `-p:ProduceReferenceAssemby=true` as Argument to `dotnet build`). But there are no ref folders in my output directory.

If I use `ProducyOnlyReferenceAssembly` instead, the produced DLL is correctly a Reference Assembly, but not in a ref subfolder but directly in the output folder.

There are ref folders and ref assemblies in my obj folder. But I don't think that these are the correct files, or are they?

I found nothing so far, why it didn’t work. All sources suggest the this property should lead to ref dlls being created in the output folder.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the solcution on this site:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/6.0/write-reference-assemblies-to-obj

It seems Microsoft changed the default behaviour. But in most other documents that has not been updated.

Since .NET 6.0 the reference assemblies are generated in the obj folder (or technically the "IntermediateOutputPath") in the subfolder "refint".

---

This behaviour can be changed by using the `ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir` MSBUILD property or by using the `TargetRefPath` property to get the resulting path.